# how do we specify Must clause(+) with local params

Tags: solr, lucene

if my query is using local params e.g like below

```
q=\field:test11&
fq=+{!frange cost=200 l=NOW/DAY-10DAYS u=NOW/DAY+1DAY incl=true incu=false}date
```

How to i specify the must clause ?

So adding + at the beginning of the local param syntax is the correct way?

e.g in the first query, is the leading + correct or not?

```
+{!frange cost=200 l=NOW/DAY-10DAYS u=NOW/DAY+1DAY incl=true incu=false}date
```

If not then how do we specify must clause or do we even need must clause here ?

**The intent of my query is to find all the documents which have value test11 in field and also the date is within last 10 days.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query will work as its written if you remove the `+`. A filter query is always used to *filter* the current set of returned documents, so it *has* to match (i.e. it'll always work logically as an AND clause to the original query).

You can probably rewrite that query to just be a range as well:

```
fq=start_date:[NOW/DAY-10DAYS TO NOW]
```

Comment: I need to add cost to this so to use as postfiler that is why using the local param syntax

Comment: So essentially + is implied for all the filter queries ?

Comment: Yes, a filter query will give a set of documents that the original query is intersected with - if the filter query does not match, the document is excluded.